# Not able to run XCtest case on Simulator using jenkins

Tags: mac-osx, jenkins, ios

I am getting below error while running XCTest test cases on simulator on jenkins:

The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10810.)

It happening because Jenkins run as daemon. So, I did all changes as mentioned in below link to make it starting at boot time itself:

http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/

But still after doing all the changes, Jenkins process does not start after reboot.

Also checked the owner for /var/log/Jenkins/Jenkins.log and it is correct.

NB: MAC OS - Seirra 10.12.3

Answer (score 0):

I use Jenkins on a Sierra macMini installed via homebrew and running as a daemon (LaunchAgent) under the logged in Mac user. I am able to run unit tests against the simulator just fine using [fastlane's scan tool](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/scan#readme). I used the [brew services cask](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/installing-jenkins-osx-yosemite.html) to install as a LaunchAgent that will start when the user is logged into the mac. I have not attempted to use the official packaged installer package for Mac because I read too many horror stories about things like user permissions, simulator issues etc.

The help article you linked to advises to run Jenkins as a LaunchAgent like I mention above. Do you absolutely *need* to have it run as a LaunchDaemon (non-user-specific) that starts upon a reboot **before** login or can you live with running it as a LaunchAgent (user-specific) that starts only **after** you login?

As far as why it's not starting after a reboot - have you logged in yet? If you have, ensure your ~/Library/LaunchAgents directory contains the valid plist file to start the jenkins process.